# Xna ContentManager won't recognise my texture

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have a problem with loading a .png file from my content.
It gives me the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll
>   Additional information: Error loading "Textures\BlockBlack". File not found.

The weird thing is that it will load some other textures but not this one and i don't know why.

The texture is a 16x16 black .png texture,
Assest Name is BlockBlack,
Build Action is Content,
Content Importer is Texture - XNA Framework,
Content Processor is Texture - XNA Framework,

It is set to Do not copy,
File Name is BlockBlack.png.

The content root directory is `content` and the texture is saved in `Content/Textures/BlockBlack.png`. I gave the `assetname` as `Textures/BlockBlack`.

Does anyone have any idea why it won't load?

Comment: could you show code where you load texture?

Comment: I have solved already solved it. The problem was that i needed to set it to compile instead of content.